# Detect hiding and showing of softkeyboard in Android without setting windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize

Tags: android

There seems to be a couple of ways to detect the hiding and showing of the softkeyboard in Android, such as the answers given here:

[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

However, these all rely on the `windowSoftInputMode` to be set to `adjustResize`. In my case other Views in the same Activity require the `windowSoftInputMode` to be set to `adjustPan` which means the `windowSoftInputMode` needs to be individually toggled by the Views which is not an ideal solution.

Does anyone know a way to detect the hiding and showing of the softkeyboard **without** setting the `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method for showing softkeyboard without using `windowSoftInputMode` -

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```